# Compiling answers as HTML, PDF, whatever

Tags: feature-request, pdf

I would like to collect all the answers of a specific user (e.g. John Rennie in *physics*, and also my own answers on *philosophy*). I don't care if the result is HTML or PDF.

Is such result possible in SE?

I've already checked [Stack Overflow anthology project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40134/stack-overflow-anthology-project) and that doesn't answer my question, the approach there is to generate a book, I don't need a book (although it would be nice), what I need is the collection of results of a user. Other nice-to-have would be selecting some answers or questions and generate a page/PDF.

Comment: maybe use sede: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/dump-of-my-own-stack-exchange-content/269951#269951

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users) to obtain the raw HTML and transform it in the programming language you're familiar with. There's no built-in option for this, and IMHO it's not likely to be built; it'll take a lot of time and not many people will use this feature.

For example, the [following call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=23407&filter=!8Ifzx5dnl0UEwdCRJkv_y&site=philosophy&run=true) will return all answers [you](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/23407/rodolfoap) posted on Philosophy Stack Exchange:

[image]

You can change the filter to add more details to the answer.